# MATCH AGAINST Query issue

Tags: mysql, sql, match-against

I have a problem with MATCH AGAINST, when i'm trying to find a record. In my users table i have a user with the following data:

first_name: Alejandra Maria de los Angeles
last_name: Quintero Barreiro Gutierrez

when i try to make the following queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles
INNER JOIN users ON articles.author_id = users.id
WHERE MATCH(first_name,last_name) AGAINST('Alejanra Gutierrez')

SELECT * 
FROM articles
INNER JOIN users ON articles.author_id = users.id
WHERE MATCH(first_name,last_name) AGAINST('A Barreiro')

SELECT * 
FROM articles
INNER JOIN users ON articles.author_id = users.id
WHERE MATCH(first_name,last_name) AGAINST('los angeles')
```

All queries are returning correct information, but if the search is replace for "de los" which is in the first_name, the query doesn't work.

Someone have some idea why or can help me with this?

P.D. The tables were in InooDB with MySQL 5.6.15 but i changed it by MyISAM. When i had InooDB this kind of queries was working but with the engine change doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

MySQL full text search ignores words shorter than 4 characters by default.  Read about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html):

> The minimum and maximum lengths of words to be indexed are defined by
>   the innodb_ft_min_token_size and innodb_ft_max_token_size for InnoDB
>   search indexes, and ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len for MyISAM
>   ones. After changing any of these options, rebuild your FULLTEXT
>   indexes for the change to take effect. For example, to make
>   two-character words searchable, you could put the following lines in
>   an option file

(Okay, that reference doesn't specify that the default is "4", but it is.)

Follow the instructions:  change the default and rebuild the index.

Comment: The reference for _"default 4"_ is [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) (so not just "but it is"). Just noticing.